# raspberry pi python-tesseract install

Tags: raspbian, python, image

A few months ago I created a project that uses the python-tesseract library on the raspberry pi. Since then I reinstalled rasbpian, and now I would like to reinstall the python-tesseract libary. The problem I'm having is that the library doesn't install anymore on the raspberry pi. The raspberry-pi was never officially supported, but it could be installed. The installition process I used a few months ago, doesn't work anymore and I tried everything I could find but nothing worked. Did anyone lately install python-tesseract on the pi? If yes, how?

python 2.7

Raspbian fully up-to-date (including firmware)

Answer (score 2):

So after some searching and trying everything that I could come up with, I have found a way that works. This commands below work, but it is still a little raw, a lot of the installed dependencies are unnecessary. The 0.7.4 version that is used is not on the official website so it took some time to find it. But I hope some I help some people with the same problem!

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng libopencv-dev libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev python-all-dev swig libcv-dev python-opencv python-numpy python-setuptools build-essential subversion

sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng tesseract-ocr-dev libleptonica-dev python-all-dev swig libcv-dev

sudo svn checkout http://python-tesseract.googlecode.com/svn/python-tesseract-0.7.4/

sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```